# Publishing Time - WordPress Plain White Screen with No Error

Tags: errors

Publishing Time - WordPress Plain White Screen with No Error.

Whenever I try to publish something, WordPress shows the following page with no error.

[image: wordpress white screen with no error]

Yes, pages and posts are getting publishing but no error message. I don't understand, what's wrong with it? How can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by a PHP fatal error occurs while saving the post. The error source is one of your plugins or the current theme, so to troubleshoot, follow these steps:

1. Try to enable [the debug log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG) and take a look at the log (usually in: wp-content/debug.log)  to see if you can find the error.
2. Deactivate all plugins and set the default theme of Wordpress
3. Now start activating the plugins (and the theme) one by one and every time you enable one test to check if the issue arises.
4. Sometimes this is not caused by a specific plugin or theme but the website consumes the allowed memory. If the previous steps don't help, try to [increase the allowed memory size](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/increasing-the-wordpress-memory-limit/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable guideline. I will test this today and inform you soon.

Comment: I found following errors after following your steps: `PHP Notice: Undefined index: License-form-method in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/Ultimate_VC_Addons/admin/bsf-core/BSF_License_Manager.php on line 619`
`PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-includes/post-template.php:427) in /var/www/html/wp-admin/post.php on line 210`
`PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-includes/post-template.php:427) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1223`

Comment: It looks like Ultimate Addons for VC is throwing errors at this point preventing Wordpress from loading normally. Try to deactivate this plugin and test if publishing goes well.