# PHP Error in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, themes, errors

So I'm having some issues with an AWS multisite hosting of wordpress. Every couple of weeks my entire instance of websites goes down. The first time it happened I was getting 500 errors so I just restarted the instance & everything was fine. But the second time there were no 500 errors, and while restarting worked, I'd ideally like to solve the issue entirely so I dug a bit deeper & looked at my php error logs & found this:

"PHP WARNING: Declaration of my_menu_walker::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0) in {filepath} on line 61"

Essentially there is some kind of issue with a line of code in the theme on one of my hosted sites, but as it's not a theme I created or anything like that I have no idea how to fix it. Here's the full class that's having issues. Line 61 is the last line of this class before the closing }'s.

```
class my_menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {

        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

          $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

          $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
          $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
          $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
          $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
          $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

           if($depth != 0) 
                  $description = $append = $prepend = "";

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
            $item_output .= $args->link_before.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;
            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Normally I would just send issues like this to the theme maker's support, but this theme is so old that I no longer have access to support from the theme maker without paying a large sum so if I can resolve it without doing that, that would be ideal.

Comment: The warning you mentioned is not a cause of the failure of your instance. This is just a PHP warning that doesn't affect website loading or even performance. You need to look for **Fatal** errors in your logs. If you can't find any, try with Apache error logs you may find something there.

Comment: Follow the steps in this answer to resolve your issue: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/325869/97257

Answer (score 0):

Replcace this

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) { ....
```

with this

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) { ....
```

I hope this will work.